# Microstack "neutron net-create" equivalent command

Tags: openstack-neutron, microstack

How to run the following command with Microstack

```
neutron net-create mgmt --provider:network_type=vlan --provider:physical_network=physnet_em1 --provider:segmentation_id=500 --shared
```

I tried:

```
microstack.openstack network create mgmt --provider:network_type=vlan --provider:physical_network=physnet_em1 --provider:segmentation_id=500 --shared
usage: openstack network create [-h] [-f {json,shell,table,value,yaml}]
                                [-c COLUMN] [--noindent] [--prefix PREFIX]
                                [--max-width <integer>] [--fit-width]
                                [--print-empty] [--share | --no-share]
                                [--enable | --disable] [--project <project>]
                                [--description <description>] [--mtu <mtu>]
                                [--project-domain <project-domain>]
                                [--availability-zone-hint <availability-zone>]
                                [--enable-port-security | --disable-port-security]
                                [--external | --internal]
                                [--default | --no-default]
                                [--qos-policy <qos-policy>]
                                [--transparent-vlan | --no-transparent-vlan]
                                [--provider-network-type <provider-network-type>]
                                [--provider-physical-network <provider-physical-network>]
                                [--provider-segment <provider-segment>]
                                [--dns-domain <dns-domain>]
                                [--tag <tag> | --no-tag]
                                <name>
openstack network create: error: unrecognized arguments: --provider:network_type=vlan --provider:physical_network=physnet_em1 --provider:segmentation_id=500 --shared
```

I did not find fast information related to this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should read the manual?

```
microstack.openstack network create mgmt --provider-network-type vlan --provider-physical-network physnet_em1 --provider-segment 500
```

neutron-cli is outdated and will not longer be updated

Comment: Could you add the link to the online manual?

Comment: @ClipHive Maybe first you should provide the link to the online manual, which clearly we dont have in the official page of Microstack: https://microstack.run/docs . Second, maybe you can pay attention to the date the question was asked: June 2020. Even if we now had documentation, probably that time we didnt since I searched and didnt find.

Comment: So since microstack.openstack is the "mini" version from openstack you just have to adapt to the `python-openstackclient`. If you set the alias for `microstack.openstack` to `openstack` you will have the same features available. 

@YLR sorrry for the delayed answer. Hereby the docs
[python-openstackcli](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest)/cli/index.html

@DaltonCézane You are right there is no documentation at this point. But its just a "mini" Openstack. You only had to adapt to the existing documentation.

Comment: @YLR sorry I broke the link..
[python-openstackcli](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/index.html)